# update RecyclerView after onclick buttom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a shopping cart
In this cart, I want to click on the plus button
My RecyclerView will be upgraded

In this cart, I want to click on the minus button
My RecyclerView will be upgraded

And also click on the delete button to delete the item from the RecyclerView
Thank you very much for your help

**Code**:

```
public class ShopCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopCartAdapter.ShopCartHolder> {
List<ShopCartGet> mDataset;
Context context;
 String email,password;
List<ShopCartGet> list;
ShopCartAdapter adapter;

public class ShopCartHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title,price;
    TextView number_order,priceall;
    ImageView img,delete,minus,plus;
    Spinner sp;
    TextView id;
    int currentNos;
    int ids=0;
    public void update(List<ShopCartGet> list) {  
        mDataset = list; 
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
    public void increment(){
         currentNos = Integer.parseInt(number_order.getText().toString()) ;
        number_order.setText(String.valueOf(++currentNos));
        ids = Integer.parseInt(id.getText().toString());
         email= ShopCart.string_from_sp;
         password = ShopCart.string_from_sp1;
    }
   
    public void update() {
        String BASE_URL = "http://laravel.cahoo.ir/json/android/update_basket.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("order_id", String.valueOf(ids));
                params.put("number_order", String.valueOf(currentNos));
                params.put("password", password);                 
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return super.getHeaders();
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    public void delete() {
        String BASE_URL = "xxx";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("order_id", String.valueOf(ids));
                params.put("number_order", String.valueOf(currentNos));
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return super.getHeaders();
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public ShopCartHolder(View itemView) { 
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_info);
        number_order = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_order);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        priceall = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceall);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_mahsol);
        delete = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.delet);
        minus =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        plus = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ids);
        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view ) {
                increment();        
                update();
            }
        });       
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                delete();
            }  });   } }
public ShopCartAdapter(Context context, List<ShopCartGet> myDataset) { 
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public ShopCartAdapter.ShopCartHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { 
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.sample_shop_cart, parent, false); 
    ShopCartAdapter.ShopCartHolder dataObjectHolder = new ShopCartAdapter.ShopCartHolder(view);
    return dataObjectHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShopCartAdapter.ShopCartHolder holder, final int position) { 
    holder.title.setText(mDataset.get(position).title);  
    holder.price.setText(mDataset.get(position).price);
    holder.number_order.setText(mDataset.get(position).number_order);
    holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset.get(position).id));
    holder.priceall.setText(mDataset.get(position).pricall);   
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() { 
    return mDataset.size();
}}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly? What are the problems you are experiencing with your current code?  What have you done to try and solve your problem?

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My problem is that when I click on the Plus button
  I want to recyclerview to be upgraded

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
make interface to handle plus and minus click event like below you make two interface for handling plus and minus..
define interface into adapter class..

```
   OnItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface OnItemClick {
    void getPosition(String data); //pass any things
}
```

after click event into onBind method..

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    final String data = mStringList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(data);
    holder.pulshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition(data);
        }
    });
}
```

after that adapter bind into recyclerview it means adapter not null then call below code..

```
        adpater.setOnItemClick(new RecyclerViewAdpater.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition(String data) {
            Log.d("Data of Click::",data);
            adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ShopCartGet customModal;
List list;

```
  public void updateView(int index, String data){
        customModal = list.get(index);
        customModal.setStatus(data);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(index, getItemCount() - index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```